# WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined during Gatsby build

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-props

I'm building my personal portfolio using graphmcms and Gatsby. The project runs perfect in local environment. While running gatsby build it returns
error

**Child Component .js (Component where error throws during build )**

```
{
  props.images.map((el, idx) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={el.url} alt="img" />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

**Parent component.js**

```
//Query
    
<StaticQuery
query={graphql`
{
  Project {
    images {
        url(transformation: {document: {output: {format: webp}}})
      }
    }
  `}
```

**Child Component**

```
<Child images= {home.images.url} />
```

Comment: Can you provide the full `StaticQuery` component?

Answer (score 1):

**You issue might be laying somewhere else which cause the `props.images` to be empty during the initial render**

But you could try to check if it's existing first then render it:

```
{
  props?.images && props.images.map((el, idx) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={el.url} alt="img" />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes , it exists when I console.log(el) I get the data

Comment: Yeah, Did you try to log in to the deployed app? It might only available on the 2nd render